# echo server distorting image response body

Tags: go

Trying to write a simple echo server for images, but it distorts the file. What's going wrong?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
)

type FlushWriter struct {
    w io.Writer
}

func (fw *FlushWriter) Write(bytes []byte) (int, error) {
    count, e := fw.w.Write(bytes)
    fw.w.(http.Flusher).Flush()
    return count, e
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", index)
    fmt.Println("listening on 8000")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}

func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "image/jpeg")
    fw := &FlushWriter{ w: w }
    io.Copy(fw, r.Body)
}
```

And to test it.

```
$ curl --data-binary @image.jpg -o test.jpg localhost:8000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're ignoring errors in your code, and missing a `ErrBodyReadAfterClose`.

You can't read from the `http.Request.Body` once you start writing to the `http.ResponseWriter`

http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#pkg-variables

> ErrBodyReadAfterClose is returned when reading a Request or Response
>   Body after the body has been closed. This typically happens when the
>   body is read after an HTTP Handler calls WriteHeader or Write on its
>   ResponseWriter

You'll need to buffer the image on the server before writing it back.

Aside from the fact that Go won't let you do this, even if you were to make a handler that worked, most clients would cause this to deadlock with images larger than the sum of all the buffers involved. This requires a client that can simultaniously send and receive, which very few, if any would do.

Comment: Really interesting. Thank you.